# Spring data elastic search date issue when search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.4 and elasticsearch 7.12.1 and basically am able to insert  a document with createDate as field successfully but unable to search.

I have a Spring rest webservice that contains search functionality that search by range of date and contains the request in json below:

```
{

  "dateTo": "20210901T152702.620+04:00",
  "dateFrom": "20200901T152702.620+04:00"
```

However when execute the search of createdDate the following error is displayed  :

```
021-09-01 15:45:18.149  WARN 19588 --- [nio-9088-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "20210901T152702.620+04:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '20210901T152702.620+04:00' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "20210901T152702.620+04:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '20210901T152702.620+04:00' could not be parsed at index 0e
```

Please find below my document:

```
public class Logging {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "username")
    private String username;


    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate = ZonedDateTime.now();


}
```

My request is shown below:

```
public class LoggingSearchCriteria extends AbstractSearchRequest {

     
    private ZonedDateTime dateTo;

    private ZonedDateTime dateFrom;
}
```

Any idea why I am getting this error when executing the search command?

Thnks in advance

Comment: This must be an error coming from the REST implementation where the json request is parsed. Spring Data Elasticsearch  does not use Jackson on in- or output data

Comment: I removed the [[spring-data-jpa]] tag since it doesn't seem to be relevant.